# Image SRC and encoding troubles

Tags: php, html, image, encoding

Hi I have problem with encoding.

Images doesn't work when I am using polish characters like(ą,ł,ę,ó etc.) in src adress.

Lets look:

On the server I have file: żyrandol.jpg. It works and file name is correct. Without any encoding problems.

**http://imgur.com/Rg7rZP8**

When I check source code. Everything is fine too (I believe).

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4hcx.jpg**

Than I am going deeper and I see that my file has encoded name:

**imgur.com/GS0meFa**

And finally if I try open image directly in browser I have error message:

**imgur.com/TrpBlMt**

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: It's simple, stop saving files with UTF Encoding names. You will always get errors and their are very hard to search. Sanitize the files.

Comment: But I need to have a polish names of dirs and files on server.

Comment: Why not use regular names on the server end and UTF encoded names on the html end?

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks for responding

Comment: @user3100021 he was suggesting to sanitize to regular names and add another field in your database with original name.

Comment: I dont have database. I am using Dir system. For example: I have dir: img/my new house/img1.jpg and my script generate: <h2>my new house</h2><a href=img/my new house/img1.jpg">..</a>